# How can an inherited copyright be released under a Creative Commons license?

Tags: copyright, law

Alice created a work and died without publishing it. Bob and Charlie jointly inherited the copyright. Bob wants to release it under a license of his choice without involving Charlie. Can he do this? If so, how?

Comment: I think this is more of a law question than a free software one.  I know some jurisdictions have the concepts of *ownership in joint* and *ownership in common*, one being where either party may unilaterally dispose of half the asset, the other being where the asset may only be disposed of whole, and only under the consent of both parties.  How copyright as a shared legacy is regarded will be jurisdictionally-dependent, and may also depend on how the will was written.  None of those issues is really a free software one.  Would you like me to transfer this question to law.SE?

Comment: @MadHatter I think it would probably be closed as an RSLA there, but if it's off-topic here, then sure, you can migrate it and we'll see how it's received there. Thank you!

Comment: I'll wait a bit for the community to express an opinion.  If it  starts attracting downvotes or close votes, I'll think about throwing it across the fence.

Comment: My rule of thumb is that if the answer would remain unchanged if you replace every instance of an open source specific term in a question with a non-open source term, then the question is probably off-topic here because it's not really about open source; hence I’m voting to close this question because I could replace "Creative Commons" with "Proprietary License 13".

Comment: I think it is clearly off topic here, this question is about inheritance law, which is likely specific to the jurisdiction governing Alice's copyright, and about copyright law (jurisdiction specific) w.r.t. governance of joint/shared ownership of copyright by Bob and Charlie.